# Extracting SubjectAlternativeName from X509 in Java

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

I'm extracting the SubjectAlternativeName from a X509 Certificate in Java, and it seems to be returning something like

```
[2, domain.example.com ]
```

Is this standard? And what does the `2` in the value stand for? Currently i'm parsing out just 2, but I don't want to deploy the code and find out that `2` isn't a standard output from the certificate.

This is my code

```
    X509Certificate[] clientCert = (X509Certificate[]) req
    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

senderDomain = clientCert[0].getSubjectAlternativeNames().toArray()[0]
    .toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in [`X509Certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectAlternativeNames%28%29) (also from the [X.509 specification, section 8.3.2.1](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.509-200811-I/en)):

```
 GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
      otherName                       [0]     OtherName,
      rfc822Name                      [1]     IA5String,
      dNSName                         [2]     IA5String,
      x400Address                     [3]     ORAddress,
      directoryName                   [4]     Name,
      ediPartyName                    [5]     EDIPartyName,
      uniformResourceIdentifier       [6]     IA5String,
      iPAddress                       [7]     OCTET STRING,
      registeredID                    [8]     OBJECT IDENTIFIER}
```

So 2 is for DNS names (host names when you verify a server certificate), which is quite common. (If you're expecting an IP address, it's 7 you should look for.)